# How to load image as map in osmdroid

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

maybe my question is so stupid, but... I would like to load image into map. I mean, I need to have all possibilities to draw markers on my map, but a background should be totally custom. Is it possible with osmdroid or something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [custom tilesource](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources) with youre image sliced into tiles (tiles are little square images containign little areas of map for particular zoom).  So you'll have to slice your image and place slices in a proper directory structure according to their golocation. I guess you can find plenty of tools which can help you with slicing. If you don't have more "zooms" of the image you can lock mapview in one particluar zoom (so zooming will not work).